# Checking user role and redirects them to different page

Tags: php

i am currently new to php and only know the basics and am trying to develop a website for my project. I am able to create a login system but i can't seem to redirect users to different page based on the role that they have. What i'm trying to do is when they log in, a script will pop showing a message saying 'welcome "user"' and then it redirects them to different pages according to their role.

This is my current code:

```php
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
  if ($pwdCheck == false) {
     header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
       exit();
  }
  elseif ($pwdCheck == true) {
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
     $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];
     $_SESSION['userRole'] = $row['roleUsers'];
  }
  if ($_SESSION['userRole']==="1") {
     header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
     exit();
  }
  elseif ($_SESSION['userRole']==="0") {
     header("Location: ../adminhomepage.php?login=success");
     exit();
  }
}
else {
  header("Location: ../index.php?error=nouser");
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Check your bind statement, the logic looks okay, but you use $mailuid twice, is this correct?

Comment: What does your code do at the moment?  Which redirect if any does it try?

Comment: show your `$stmt`, and also var_dump your `$result` to make sure there are records found

Answer (score 0):

for checking true or false, you don't need to use `elseif` statement

```php
  $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
  if ( !$pwdCheck ) {
     header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
       exit();
  }
  else {
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
     $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];
     $_SESSION['userRole'] = $row['roleUsers'];
  }
```

Comment: While this is true, how does this help with redirecting users to different pages according to their role?

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not answer the question, I just corrected the password checking process. Your comment on the question might be enlightening

Comment: You have not corrected the password checking process.  You have just rewritten the logic.